# 2D Matrix STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION error

Tags: c++, exception, parallel-processing

Im having a problem with my code atm and Im not sure what the issue is since I get a Status Access Violation exception when I manipulate the array in the startFire function. Im pretty sure there isn't any array out of bounds errors going on, but maybe I don't see it : / or its a pointer/reference error that Im not seeing. Hope another pair of eyes can take a look.

Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string cfile, ccommand;
int cnum1,cnum2,cnum3,cnum4,cx;
//bool fired = false;
bool flag = true;
const double h = .2;

/*
 * 
 */

void printMatrix(double **x, int n)
{
    int size = n;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            std:: cout << x[i][j] << " " ;
        }
        std:: cout << std::endl;
    }


}


void readFile(string file,double **x, int n)
{
    const char* filename = file.c_str();
    std::ifstream inFile(filename);

    int size = n;

    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Failed to open file " << filename;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            inFile >> x[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void startFire(double **x, int n, int it)
{
    int size = n;
    int iteration = it;

    /* Initialize 2D Array */
    double **matrix;

    matrix = new double*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        matrix[i] = new double[n];

    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
            matrix[i][j] = 0;

    for()

    for(int iter=1; iter<=iteration; iter++)
    {
        cout<<"Iteration #: "<<iter<<endl;
        for(int i=1; i<size; ++i)
        {
            for(int j=1; j<size; ++j)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = .25 *(x[i-1][j]+x[i+1][j]+x[i][j-1]+x[i][j+1]);

            }
        }
        printMatrix(matrix,size);
    }
}



void GetCommandLineArguments(int argc, char **argv,string &file, int &n, int &k, int &m, int &i)
{
    if(argc = 6)
    {
        cfile = argv[1];
        cnum1 = atoi(argv[2]);
        cnum2 = atoi(argv[3]);
        cnum3 = atoi(argv[4]);
        cnum4 = atoi(argv[5]);
    }
    file = cfile;
    n = cnum1;
    k = cnum2;
    m = cnum3;
    i = cnum4;

}



int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int k;  //Factor of n
    int m;  //Innner matrix size
    int i;  //Iteration
    int n;  //Matrix Size
    string file;
    int input;


    /*Takes in the initial cmd line values*/
    GetCommandLineArguments(argc, argv, file, n, k, m, i);


    /* Initialize 2D Array */
    double **matrix;

    matrix = new double*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        matrix[i] = new double[n];

    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
            matrix[i][j] = 0;


    /*Reads a file with numbers to make matrix*/
    readFile(file,matrix,n);

    /*Prints array displaying a matrix*/
    printMatrix(matrix,n);



    /*To call the fire command that will access the middle matrix*/
    while(flag != false)
    {
        cout<<endl
        <<"MENU:\n"
        <<"1 - Start Fire.\n"
        <<"2 - Stop Fire.\n"
        <<"3 - QUIT.\n"
        <<" Enter your choice and press return: ";
        cin >> input;

        switch(input)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"Starting fire.\n";
                startFire(matrix, n,i);
                //fired = true;

                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"Stop fire.\n";
                //fired = false;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout<<"Ending program.\n";
                flag = false;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Not a valid choice.\n";
                cout<<"Choose again.\n";
                cin>>input;
                break;
        }
    }




    return 0;
}
```

My file input called sample.input takes in the following numbers

```
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
200.0 
200.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
200.0 
200.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0 
20.0
```

Here is the error I get through cmd line.

http://i53.tinypic.com/2qu4078.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're accessing outside of the allocated array size:

```
matrix[i][j] = .25 *(x[i-1][j]+x[i+1][j]+x[i][j-1]+x[i][j+1]);
```

For kernel operations, you should really allocate the matrices one larger on each edge (+2 total), and either zero out or replicate the edge values (depending on your matrix operation).  You'll need to adjust your indices to take this offset into account.

(Alternatively, you can clamp your indices to always be inside the matrix.)

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=1; i<size; ++i)
{
    for(int j=1; j<size; ++j)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = .25 *(x[i-1][j]+x[i+1][j]+x[i][j-1]+x[i][j+1]);

    }
}
```

notice the part

```
x[i][j+1]
```

at the very last iteration i.e. i=size-1, j=size-1 that will reach outside the matrix